# Count records in a table NxN without model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

So, I'm a doubt.

In my app, I have a table called user_profiles_mobile_models, this table have two columns:
user_profile_id int(11) PK 
mobile_model_id int(11) PK

But I have two models, UserProfile and MobileModel.

```
class UserProfile
  ...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :mobile_models, join_table: 'user_profiles_mobile_models', order: 'name'
  ...
```

I need count how many users have a mobile model with id 1,7,8...

Its possible do that?

Thanks and sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in your model MobileModel you have a

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :user_profiles, join_table: 'user_profiles_mobile_models'
```

Then, we can use.

```
MobileModel.where('id in (?)', [1,7,8]).map(&:user_profiles).count
```